# EdgeContract when vertex names are lists

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Graphs often compress a great deal of information into a simple visualizable structure. So it is not uncommon that vertex labels include more information than a simple index. For example, vertex labels might be lists.  Graph handles this brilliantly:

```
graph = Graph[{{1, 2} \[DirectedEdge] {1, 3},
               {1, 3} \[DirectedEdge] {2, 3}, 
               {2, 3} \[DirectedEdge] {3, 2},
               {3, 2} \[DirectedEdge] {1, 2}}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

Nicely yields the graph

[image: A directed graph with vertices given as lists]

The issue here is EdgeContract. It does not seem to operate on such graphs. For example:

```
EdgeContract[graph, First[EdgeList[graph]]]
```

returns exactly the same graph. It does not contract the first edge.

Comment: Did you contact Wolfram to report this bug? If not, please do so.

Comment: Not fixed in 13.0 Prerelease 1. 13.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (October 11, 2021).

Comment: Now fixed in Version 13.2 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit).

Answer (score 1):

One work-around is to covert the vertex names into strings:

```
sgraph = Graph[Map[ToString[First[#]] \[DirectedEdge] ToString[Last[#]] &, 
                    EdgeList[graph]], VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

(I'm sure someone has a more elegant method for doing this)
That produces the same graph but with the vertex names as strings instead of lists.

Now EdgeContract works:

```
EdgeContract[sgraph, First[EdgeList[sgraph]]]
```

correctly yields:

[image: Directed graph with the first edge contracted]

I suppose another alternative is a dictionary that maps labels to their information.  But wouldn't it be nice if this added step weren't required?